# Customized OAUTH2.0 with WSO2 API Manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I am new to WSO2 API Manager and Identity Server. I have one requirement -  to use customized OAUTH2.0 in WSO2 IS with WSO2 API Manager. Could you please let me know If there are any samples or examples for this requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You can register your custom Oauth Provider as IDP in WSO2 Identity Server. You can refere this blog [[Federated Authentication] OpenID-Connect IDP with WSO2 Identity Server](http://xacmlinfo.org/2015/01/08/federated-authentication-integrating-openid-connect-idp/) on how to do that.

WSO2 API Manager don't support this. So, You have to combine WSO2 Identity Server with API Manager ([Identity Server as Key Manager with API Manager](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER420/Configuring+WSO2+Identity+Server+as+the+Key+Manager)).